# How to fix ghost entries in android listview?

Tags: android, firebase, android-listview

I am fetching my data from firebase and everything is working fine but in the listview, I am getting ghost entries (items) as shown below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQLDL.jpg
"this is the screenshot from device"

here is my code where I am fetching and displaying the listview items

```
    public void displayNearTopics(GeoQuery locGeoQuery) {

    //Log.d(TAG, "SharedPref, new topics: "+prefs.getInt(NO_NEW_TOPICS,0));

    locTopics.clear();
    loctopicId.clear();
    locTopicsListAdapter = new TopicsListAdapter(getActivity(), locTopics, loctopicId);
    mTopicsRecyclerView.setAdapter(locTopicsListAdapter);
    //mTopicsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mTopicsRecyclerView.showShimmerAdapter();
    mTopicsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    locGeoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyEntered(final String key, GeoLocation location) {
            //key is the topic key
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The retrieved keys are:" + key, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mTopicsRecyclerView.hideShimmerAdapter();
            Log.d(TAG, "Key entered:"+ key);
            if(bottomNavigation.getCurrentItem()!=2){
                int currentCount = prefs.getInt(NO_NEW_TOPICS, 0)+1;

                Log.d(TAG, "ONKEYENTERED, SharedPref, new topics, current count: "+currentCount);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putInt(NO_NEW_TOPICS, currentCount);
                editor.apply();
                Log.d(TAG, "ONKEYENTERED, SharedPref, new topics, shared ref: "+prefs.getInt(NO_NEW_TOPICS, 0));
                //bottomNavigation.setNotification(String.valueOf(currentCount),2);
                //bottomNavigation.refresh();

            }
            else{
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.putInt(NO_NEW_TOPICS, 0);
                editor.apply();
            }
            DatabaseReference topicRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child(FirebaseValues.TOPICS_TABLE).child(key);
            topicRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Topics tempTopic;
                    tempTopic = dataSnapshot.getValue(Topics.class);


                    locTopics.add(0, tempTopic);
                    loctopicId.add(0, key);
                    locTopicsListAdapter.notifyItemInserted(locTopics.size() - 1);
                    swipeRefTopic.setRefreshing(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyExited(String key) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryReady() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });


}
```

I am using firebase geofire to get the keys which are withing the given radius. Everything is working perfectly except I am getting some unknown items in my listview. Also these go away once I scroll down enough and then scroll back up.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're notifying the incorrect position.

```
// Inserting item at index 0.
locTopics.add(0, tempTopic);
// Updating position at the end of the list.
locTopicsListAdapter.notifyItemInserted(locTopics.size() - 1);
```

You should change your `notifyItemInserted` to pass `0`.

```
locTopicsListAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
```